# Filter webhook payload for modified repositories

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm building a pipeline with Gitlab and AWX and need to filter the payload of the webhook. What I need is basically parsing only project1 and project2 (which is between two /) into a variable which I can use in other roles.

```
tower_webhook_payload:
  after: 
  before: 
  checkout_sha: 
  commits:
    - id: 
      message: 
      title:  
      timestamp: 
      url: >-
        author:
        name: 
        email: 
      added: []
      modified:
        - repository/project1/file1
      removed: []
    - id: 
      message:
      title: 
      timestamp: 
      url: >-
      author:
        name: 
        email: 
      added: 
      modified:
        - repository/project2/file2
      removed: []
```

This was my rough idea but I don't have much experience working with lists or regex.

```
- debug: msg="{{ tower_webhook_payload.commits | select('match', 'modified') | list }}"

"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ tower_webhook_payload.commits | select('match', 'modified') | list }}): expected string or bytes-like object"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this:

1. extract the `modified` list attribute of each `commits`.
2. flatten the result so you get a single list of all gathered elements.
3. map the `regex_replace` filter to each element to extract only the project name. The below regex capture everything after the initial `repository/` that does not contain a `/` and replaces the entire match only with that capture
4. apply the `unique` filter so you eliminate duplicates if any

```yaml
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tower_webhook_payload.commits | map(attribute='modified') | flatten
      | map('regex_replace', 'repository/([^/]*)/.*', '\\1') | unique }}"
```

---

Edit: with older versions of ansible, you might have to explicitely cast to list after maping

```yaml
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tower_webhook_payload.commits | map(attribute='modified')
      | list | flatten
      | map('regex_replace', 'repository/([^/]*)/.*', '\\1')
      | list | unique }}"
```

Comment: [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_ok) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.awx_display.CallbackModule object at
0x7f6b9d1f3fd0>): Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Can you please add your playbook ? Because the above works with your example data in a simple playbook launched directly on the command line with ansible_playbook.

Comment: The playbook is empty except for the debug msg. However as I said I'm using ansible tower. Ansible version 2.8.5 and AWX 9.0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

how about using `json_query` like:

```
    - debug: msg="{{ tower_webhook_payload | json_query(\"commits[].modified[0]\") }}"
```